# Checking ActiveRecord Associations in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, bdd

I am learning how to write test cases using Rspec. I have a simple Post Comments Scaffold where a Post can have many Comments. I am testing this using Rspec. How should i go about checking for `Post :has_many :comments`. Should I stub `Post.comments` method and then check this with by returning a mock object of array of comment objects? Is testing for AR associations really required ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since ActiveRecord associations should be well-tested by the Rails test suite (and they are), most people don't feel the need to make sure they work -- it's just assumed that they will.

If you want to make sure that your model is *using* those associations, that's something different, and you're not wrong for wanting to test that. I like to do this using the [shoulda](http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) gem. It lets you do neat things like this:

```
describe Post do
  it { should have_many(:comments).dependent(:destroy) }
end
```

Comment: Woops, double check that. I meant the Shoulda gem, not factory_girl.

Answer (score 12):

Testing associations is good practice generally, especially in an environment where TDD is highly regarded- other developers will often look to your specs before looking at the corresponding code. Testing associations makes sure that your spec file most accurately reflects your code.

Two ways you can test associations:

1. With FactoryGirl:

   ```
   expect { FactoryGirl.create(:post).comments }.to_not raise_error
   ```

   This is a relatively superficial test that will, with a factory like:

   ```
   factory :post do
     title { "Top 10 Reasons why Antelope are Nosy Creatures" }
   end
   ```

   return you a NoMethodError if your model lacks a `has_many` association with comments.
2. You can use the ActiveRecord [#reflect_on_association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association) method to take a more in-depth look at your association. For instance, with a more complex association:

   ```
   class Post
     has_many :comments, through: :user_comments, source: :commentary
   end
   ```

   You can take a deeper look into your association:

   ```
   reflection = Post.reflect_on_association(:comment)
   reflection.macro.should eq :has_many
   reflection.options[:through].should eq :user_comments
   reflection.options[:source].should eq :commentary
   ```

   and test on whatever options or conditions are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather not use an external gem like [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) to test your associations (see [Robert Speicher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223897/robert-speicher)'s [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2673214/1157054) for details on that), another option is to use [`reflect_on_association`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association) to get the `AssociationReflection` object for the relevant association, and then assert on that:

```
describe Post do
  it "should destroy its comments when it is destroyed" do
    association = Post.reflect_on_association(:comments)

    expect(association).to_not be_nil
    expect(association.options[:dependent]).to eq :destroy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people don't test the associations, as Rails already has unit tests to make sure those methods work correctly.  If you are doing something complex, like involving a proc or something, you might want to explicitly test it.  Usually you can do this by just doing

```
a = Post.new
a.comments << Comment.new
assert a.save
assert a.comments.size == 1
```

or something akin to that.

Comment: I got you partially. I am new to testing. Say I write a unit test to verify that all comments are deleted when related post is deleted. So this is sufficient? Further do i even require to write a unit test to verify a destroy method generated by scaffolding.