# Deleting children does work in real app, but not in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, count, tdd, associations

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong here. I have a Client model and an Invoice model.

**Client.rb**

```
has_many :invoices, dependent: :destroy
```

**Invoices.rb**

```
belongs_to :client
```

I have the following client spec:

```
it "destroys its children upon destruction" do
  i = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice) # As per the factory, the :client is the parent of :invoice and is automatically created with the :invoice factory

  lambda {
    i.client.destroy
  }.should change(Invoice.all, :count).by(-1)
end
```

And here are my factories:

**Client factory**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    city "MyString"
  end
end
```

**Invoice factory**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :invoice do
    association :client
    gross_amount 3.14
  end
end
```

If I do `i = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice)` and afterwards `i.client.destroy` manually in the console, the invoice is in fact destroyed. But for some reason, the test fails, giving me "count should have been changed by -1, but was changed by 0".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rails tests relationships pretty well itself so most people don't bother. But you can test that your relationship is being set up properly. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673041/checking-activerecord-associations-in-rspec

Comment: Thanks, I have done that already. But just because the relationship is set up doesn't mean children get destroyed.

Comment: Yes, it's strange that they aren't being deleted in your test. Just an idea, have you tested that your factory is actually creating the associated object and saving it? I couldn't see any obvious errors otherwise though so it might just be RSpec being odd...

Comment: Yes, `i = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice)` in the console creates the invoice and its client perfectly fine... Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `Invoice.all` is an array and so database operations won't affect it. The *array* doesn't change when you destroy records, and `should change(receiver, message)` is going to just send `message` to the same `receiver`. Try either:

```
lambda {
  i.client.destroy
}.should change(Invoice, :count).by(-1)
```

or

```
lambda {
  i.client.destroy
}.should change{Invoice.all.count}.by(-1)
```